# How to set Cookie in smarty template with php?

Tags: php, smarty, setcookie

I currently have an issue with setting a cookie in a block of php code that is in a .tpl smarty template class.

In the .tpl class I have somethng like :

```
{php}
    setcookie("school", "test");
{/php}

School: { $smarty.cookies.school }
```

However this does not print out anything.  I know the php setcookie call works when its in a .php file alone, since I've tested that, but can't get it to work with the php snippet of code is in a .tpl class.

Any Advice Appreciated,
D

Comment: My advice is to not do this. Templates should only be doing display logic, not changing state.

Comment: Why can't you set the cookie from your php file then?

Comment: Yeah, I would perfer not to, but the framework i'm using has not clean hook for it and I don't want to change the base code.. =(

Comment: I don't want to modify the base code of the framework.  The framework allows me to modify specific files that are customizable and that would nto effect the base code.  The framework has consitent upgrades that may effect the changes I do to teh base code.  If it was done to the customizable part, then I dont' have to worry about upgrade issues.

Comment: Tjis is very bad practice, just saying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{php}
    setcookie("school", "test");
    $_COOKIE['school'] = 'test';
{/php}
```

It's because $_COOKIE superglobal is updated only on page refresh, not after using `setcookie()`

Make sure you are using `SmartyBC.class.php` not `Smarty.class.php` because `{php}{/php}` will not work using Smarty.class.php.

Also remember to set  `$php_handling` property to SMARTY_PHP_ALLOW.

More info http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/variable.php.handling.tpl

Comment: how do you determine if your using the SmartyBC.class.php vs. the Smarty.class.php?  This doesn't work for me so would this imply that i'm using the Smarty.class.php?  What is the difference?  Thanks,

Comment: It was not working for me with Smarty.class.php. See my updated answer.

Comment: However, eventhou I'm able to set the variable, when I go to the next page, the cookies aren't stored or set anymore.  I'm using firebug on firefox to see the set cookies.  Is there something else i'm not accounting for?

Comment: You'll also want to perform this before any HTML output on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting embedded php code into my template, I created a smarty custom function plugin that when called allows me to set cookies.

Details about custom functions:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.functions.tpl  Peter pointed me to the idea of doing this.

However, I'm still a little curious on how this can be done on the embedded php in the template code even though it isn't suggested as good practice.